# Cross validation using kNN and RF

Tags: r, imputation

I have data matrix with 50 column and 150 rows. I wanted to do cross-validation on the dataset. A subset of data look likes below:

```
>dat<-matrix(c(7,8,5,6,4,5,6,6,1,9,8,5,14,11,15,14,21,24,25,26, 31,34,35,37), nrow=8, ncol=4)
>colnames(dat)<- c("ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF")
>dat<-data.frame(dat)
```

First I wanted to replace the first value with `NA` and impute `MV` using `kNN` and `Rf`. Save the imputed values for each value in column in array for entire dataset and display the result.

Here I did something

```
 library(VIM)
 col <- names(dat)
 das <-dat
 for(name in col){  
    sp <- das[[name]]
    sp<-data.frame(sp)
    ps<-das[,-which(names(das) == name)]
    sp<-cbind(sp,ps)
for(i in 1:length(sp[,1])){
               d<-sp[,1]
               p1<-sp[,2:NCOL(sp)] 
               d[i]<-NA
               d<-data.frame(d) 
               d<-cbind(d,p1)
               mnt_im<-kNN(d,variable="d", 3)  
               mnt_m[i]<-mnt_im[i,1]
               d<-sp[,1]
       }
       #g<-assign(name, mnt_m)
       mnt_m<-data.frame(mnt_m)
       write.csv(mnt_m, "/home/Desktop/result.csv", append=TRUE)
}
```

After running above code I am getting few warnings

```
Warning messages:
1: In write.csv(mnt_m, "/home/Desktop/result.csv", append = TRUE) :
attempt to set 'append' ignored
2: In write.csv(mnt_m, "/home/Desktop/result.csv", append = TRUE) :
attempt to set 'append' ignored
3: In write.csv(mnt_m, "/home/Desktop/result.csv", append = TRUE) :
attempt to set 'append' ignored
4: In write.csv(mnt_m, "/home/Desktop/result.csv", append = TRUE) :
attempt to set 'append' ignored
```

Moreover, it is not computing the values correctly and even appending in one vector column. I want it for separate column separately.

I think there is something error in imputation.
Same thing I have to do for every variable. I am not getting what is happening exactly. Can you pinpoint the error in the code that I am doing. Also `write.csv` is not appending rightly. How can this be done for the entire dataset? I am new to R. How this can be done for `kNN` as well as `rfImpute` from the package(`randomForest`)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the packages your using as well as a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @AlexW I have edited my code with reproducible example. Thanks for comments.

Comment: This isn't really a meaningful example. You loop through a vector of length 4, inserting a single `NA` then "kNN-impute" by averaging all the other 3 values. The result is that the "MRE" is trivial and pointless. You also don't show the `rfImpute` attempt or  provide any example of such... SO users will generally help you debug your work, but not write your code / do your work for you.

Comment: @AlexW I have said I have 150 rows and 50 column dataset. Please read it carefully. Above example is just subset of dataset. After calculating the predicted imputed values, I have to calculate the avg. error. It is different thing what exactly your thinking. Also please debug the above problem as per as `rfImpute` is concern if above code is executed properly, I will do it for `rfImpute`.